# how can i avoid and allow subdirectories in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want the following url

```
http://www.mydomain.com/user.php?id=username
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/username
```

via .htaccess...

i also want to avoid subdirectory name conflict....
where i have a rewrite rule i.e

```
RewriteRule ^home/$ home.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

so my url become http://www.mydomain.com/home/
so i want this home to be ignored...in http://www.mydomain.com/username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite rules are evaluated in the order they appear. So just put your home rewrite rule first, and your username rewrite rule second, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ home.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^user.php$ $1 [NC,L]
```